# Fingerprint reader in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, lenovo, synaptics, fingerprint-reader

I'm using a Lenovo Thinkpad e580 with Ubuntu 18.04

I tried fingerprint-gui but it says "no devices found!".

lsusb command results this:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00a2 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b604 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I suspect my device is `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00a2 Synaptics, Inc.`

I tried a few online solutions, but I'm not able to find proper driver support for my system.

I found this link for [Lenovo Thinkpad L390](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201812-26720/), it also has the same fingerprint device and it is certified by the ubuntu, given all hardware support.

As I understand the driver support is available for Synaptics, Inc. 06cb:00a2, but I'm not able to find it.

Please help me in figuring this out.

Comment: Did you solve this issue, I also have the same problem.

Comment: There is a bounty for fingerprint reader support on Lenovo T480 if anyone is interested at https://www.bountysource.com/issues/56155233-add-support-for-06cb-009a.

Comment: `Synaptics` is your touchpad, not fingerprint reader

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know you don't need `fingerprint-gui` in 18.04.

You need to install these packages to get it working:

```bsh
sudo apt install -y fprintd libpam-fprintd
```

and then  update your PAM configuration.

```bsh
sudo pam-auth-update
```

Then you need to open Settings - Users, enable Fingerprint Login.

---

P.S. (if you use gnome-keyring)

Gnome-keyring is still cannot be unlocked with the fingerprint, you will need to enter your password at login or in the gnome-keyring propmt window to unlock it.

Comment: Didn't work on my Lenovo Yoga 720.

Comment: doesn't work. It cannot identify the fingerprint device. Which is why it doesn't show the fingerprint option in the user settings.

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked for me on Thinkpad L470.

Comment: didn't see any changes under `users` after making these changes

Comment: The above worked on Lenovo X1 Carbon Ubuntu 18.04 3rd Gen

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: Some readers work with https://github.com/uunicorn/python-validity . It is your best bet to use in thinkpads produced between 2017 and 2019.

There are no Linux drivers for these fingerprint readers. There's a reverse engineering project that is in progress. Also Lenovo support staff made a claim that drivers are being developed for *some* of the synaptics fingerprint readers. Right now these devices are not usuable in any Linux distro. There is no point to try.

Comment: https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90

Comment: the concerned fingerprint device (06cb:00a2) is not present in this project. Is it still helpful?

Comment: There will be a driver for these machines but nobody knows when. See: https://linuxunplugged.com/323?t=3161 .

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 20 Lenovo X1 Carbon 6th Gen. Thanks!