# How can I enable the built-in fingerprint reader on my Asus VivoBook 14 X407UF (Ubuntu 18.04)?

Tags: 18.04, asus, fingerprint-reader, additional-drivers

[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRYIa.jpg)

I have decided to use Ubuntu as my main OS. All of the drivers are properly setup except for the fingerprint reader as seen on the image. I tried following the steps on other sites but I must be doing something wrong. I even tried installing Fingerprint GUI but it still does not detect the sensor.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are the steps you've tried?

Comment: I tried these links:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049526/fingerprint-activation-on-ubuntu-18-04
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107755/fingerprint-reader-in-ubuntu-18-04
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/how-to-get-your-fingerprint-reader-working-in-ubuntu

These links were promising at first but I still couldn't get my sensor to work.